# drag a div after being dropped

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to drag a div and dro it into another div then start dragging it again. but when i drag it he loses his abbility of being dragged. I tried many things but it still doesn't work. the div is called #myDIV 
Here is the code :

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*styling here*/

#myDIV {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid #000 2px;
    background-color: #d12;
}



.ZP {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ccc;
}



.ZE {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffff99;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ZE1 {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ZE2 {
    top: 0;
    left: calc(85% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ZE3 {
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    left: calc(100% - 300px);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.ZE4 {
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(85% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ZE5 {
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ZE6 {
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(15% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ZE7 {
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    left: -200px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.ZE8 {
    top: 0;
    left: calc(15% - 250px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--The above library(/socket.io/socket.io.js) will be generated by socket.io module of server -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="ZonePartage.js"></script>
<script src="ZoneCollaborative.js"></script>
<script src="Constante.js"></script>
<script src="ZoneEchange.js"></script>
<script src="Artifact.js"></script>
<script src="Serveur.js"></script>
<script src="User.js"></script>



</head>
<body id = view>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#momo" ).draggable();
  });



</script>

<div class="content" >
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('/'); //you can replace localhost with your public domain name too!!
socket.on("message",function(artefact){  
    /*
        When server sends data to the client it will trigger "message" event on the client side , by 
        using socket.on("message") , one cna listen for the ,message event and associate a callback to 
        be executed . The Callback function gets the dat sent from the server 
    */
    console.log("Message from the server arrived")
    artefact = JSON.parse(artefact);
    console.log(artefact); /*converting the data into JS object */
    $('#myDIV').append('<div > <h1>'+artefact.title+' </h1> <h2> '+artefact.message+'</h2> </div>'); /*appending the data on the page using Jquery */

});
socket.on("image",function(image){  
    /*
        When server sends data to the client it will trigger "message" event on the client side , by 
        using socket.on("message") , one cna listen for the ,message event and associate a callback to 
        be executed . The Callback function gets the dat sent from the server 
    */
    console.log("Message from the server arrived")
    image = JSON.parse(image);
    console.log(message); /*converting the data into JS object */
    $('#yas').append('<div >'+image.data+'</div>'); /*appending the data on the page using Jquery */

});

//functions 
//function appelÃ© qd le drag commence
function dragIt(theEvent) {
//dire au navigateur ce qu'il faut glisser
theEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", theEvent.target.id);
}
//fonction appelÃ©e lorsque l'Ã©lÃ©ment drops
function dropIt(theEvent) {
//Obtenir une rÃ©fÃ©rence Ã  l'Ã©lÃ©ment dragged
var theData = theEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
//Obtenir l'Ã©lÃ©ment
var theDraggedElement = document.getElementById(theData);
//Ajouter Ã  l' Ã©lÃ©ment de drop
theEvent.target.appendChild(theDraggedElement);
//Charger le navigateur pour permettre le drop
theEvent.preventDefault();
}
</script>
<!--elements de la page-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName ("#myDIV")[0];
//ele.onmousedown = eleMouseDown;
ele.addEventListener ("mousedown" , eleMouseDown , false);

function eleMouseDown () {
    stateMouseDown = true;
    document.addEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
}

function eleMouseMove (ev) {
    var pX = ev.pageX;
    var pY = ev.pageY;
    ele.style.left = pX + "px";
    ele.style.top = pY + "px";
    document.addEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}

function eleMouseUp () {
    document.removeEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
    document.removeEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}


</script>


<div class="pics">

<div class="ZP" style="display:table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle " ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">




</div>
<div class="ZE ZE1"  ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
<img src="flower.jpg" width="80" height="80" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="ppic1" />
</div>
<span
        style="left: 527.5px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(180deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE2" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
</div>
<span
        style="left: 1176.75px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(180deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE3" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
</div>
<span
        style="left: 1405px; top: 392.5px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(270deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE4"  ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">

</div>
<span
        style="left: 1176.75px; top: 785px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>
<div class="ZE ZE5" id=momo style="text-align: center;" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
<div id="myDIV" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="pic1">
ARTEFACT
</div>
</div>
    <span
        style="left: 527.5px; top: 785px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

<div class="ZE ZE6" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
</div>
<span
        style="left: -121.75px; top: 785px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>
<div class="ZE ZE7" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
</div>
<span
        style="left: -350px; top: 392.5px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(90deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>
<div class="ZE ZE8" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
</div>
<span
        style="left: -121.75px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 200px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1) rotate(180deg); opacity: 0;"
        class="back"></span>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work in chrome though [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz7o1ggf/)

Comment: it is not what i'm looking for, a want the red div to be dragged from the yellow div and dropped into the grey div , and i continu to drag it inside the grey one.